# Chrome showing white screen and opens in small window and keyboard is not working in chrome

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, white-screen

Chrome was working fine and till yesterday. But now when click to open chrome it opens like this screenshot. There is no menu, no tab, just blank screen. I searched everywhere but got nothing. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I updated chrome 4 days back (`sudo apt update`  and then `sudo apt upgrade`), so it is latest version. I have tried to uninstall and then install it but again it is same. screenshot --> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RLCEzHZqAK4usQJJvrKPlU1ZVcmOGmzr/view?usp=sharing
Chrome is my defaul browser, so I tried to open it by hyperlink (basicly clicked on link in pdf) and this worked and chrome opened but now there is a new problem. **I cannot use keyboard in chrome.**  Just mouse and touchpad click. Please help.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUZbn.png)
thank you

Comment: That may be related to your hardware, so include system information. May also depend on customizations and extensions you may have installed. For debugging, create a new user account (temporarily) and see if the issue persists there. If not, then you know it is not hardware related, but related to user configuration settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try these steps and tell if it worked:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
```

Though let me tell you that this will reset all your bookmarks, history. This is kinda like reinstalling chrome. If you had backedup your history into your email id then you can back it up easily after doing this command.

Clear the cache:

```
rm ~/.cache/google-chrome
```

Comment: Thank  you for this, new information to me, can use in future. I restored the settings in chrome and it worked. Now it is working normal.